# How do I seed the Bug number in Bugzilla?

Tags: bugzilla

We'd like to start our bug numbers to something other than 1 for a new Bugzilla installation.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have to question your motives. Why would your first bug not be 1?

Comment: Ha!  We're moving from a paper system (yes, some places still use paper) and I'd like to "seamlessly" roll into Bugzilla.  Plus, some people are complaining about the number looking "too small".  Yeah.

Comment: I see the first one being an OK reason, although I would try to convince management that it doesn't matter (although I would enter the bugs that are not completed yet). As for the second, it's a stupid reason.

Comment: "too small"? whatinthe? I thought it was a Good Thing(tm) to not have many bugs?!?

Comment: Haha!  Stupid reason, indeed! Your managers must be more enlightened than mine.  I guess I just pick my battles... :)

Comment: I pick my battles. All of them. Because I fight for truth, justice, and the software engineering way.

Comment: At my previous job, bug number 1000 was "there are too many bugs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Bugzilla's backend, but if it uses a SQL database, you should be able to find the table that controls the bug ID number and set the autoincrement value to something else. That is, if Bugzilla uses autoincrement.

But I don't have a copy of Bugzilla to provide more info.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the responses, the following MySQL command will do it:

```
ALTER TABLE bugs AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

where 100 is the new seed number.

Here's the link to the Bugzilla [schema](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bugzilla/dbschema.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an autoincrement value in the "bugs" table.

In order to force this to start at a predefined value,

in MYSQL, you'll need to ...

- switch off autoincrement on this field.
- insert a record with a bug_id set to your starting point.
- switch the autoincrement back on.

Comment: Or you can open up the table and set the AUTOINCREMENT to a new starting value...it's much easier. Unfortunately, I only know how to do that in the MySQL Query Browser and MySQL Administrator.